# Check meter from array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects like this

```
var json = [{"price":"30.00","meter":"70"},{"price":"20.00","meter":"130"},{"price":"10.00","meter":"170"}];
```

How to check qty between this and calculate price. I wrote loop but its not working properly.

```
var mQty = 2.52;
var jCnt = json.length;
//alert(jCnt);
for (var j = 0; j < jCnt - 1; j++) {
    nextj = j + 1;
    //alert(nextj;
    first = json[j].meter;
    if (json[nextj].meter != '') {
        second = json[nextj].meter - 1;
    } else {
        second = '';
    }
    if (mQty >= first && mQty <= second) {
        //bettween meter from json obj
        alert('if condition');
        alert(json[j].price);
    } else {
        //under 70 meter
        alert('else condition');
        alert('40.00');
    }
}
```

Comment: "between this and calculate price." - what is `this` and `calculate price` ?

Comment: json[ij] is a typo... and should be json[j] ..?

Comment: if i given 2.52 means it will check bettween json object meter.

Comment: ij is wrong i changed nextj.

Comment: Please note that the problem has **nothing** to do with JSON at all. It seems you are confusing JavaScript object/array literals (constructs of the JavaScript language syntax) with JSON (a language-independent data-exchange format, like XML or CSV). I will edit your question accordingly. See also: [There is no such thing as a "JSON object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Comment: if i enter mQty  = 70; price will alert 20.00 suppose i enter 170 price will come 10.00

Comment: It's still not clear (to me) what you are trying to do. It seems you want to compare a value against a property value of each object in the array. But what exactly? Please [edit] your question and explain your problem properly.

Comment: I am calculating sq meter. if i enter 70 sqt.meter (mQty variable). It will check json meter and  get a price. Thats y i am check in loop first and second meter object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand the problem now. Your prices are per meter prices (I guess) and the more meters of something are ordered, the cheaper the price per meter. You want to find the matching price for a given length.

Since your prices are sorted in ascending order, the logic is pretty simple:

1. If the quantity/length is less than the required quantity/length of the first entry, use the default price.
2. Else use the price of the last element that has an equal or smaller quantity/length.

Example:

```
var price;
if (qty < prices[0].meter) {
    price = defaultPrice;
}
else {
    for (var i = 1; i <= prices.length; i++) {
       price = prices[i - 1].price;
       if (prices[i] && prices[i].meter > qty) {
           break;
       }
    }
}
```

If you add the default price as first element to the array:

```
var prices = [{price: defaultPrice, meter: 0}, ...];
```

then you can omit the whole `if...else` statement:

```
var price;
for (var i = 1; i <= prices.length; i++) {
    price = prices[i - 1].price;
    if (prices[i] && prices[i].meter > qty) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply and i want like this but one difference is var prices = [{"price":"40.00","meter":"0"},{"price":"30.00","meter":"70"},{"price":"20.00","meter":"130"},{"discounted_price":"10.00","meter":"170"}];

var qty = 70.23;
var price;
for (var i = 1; i < prices.length; i++) {
    price = prices[i - 1].price;
    if (prices[i].meter > qty) {
 
  alert(prices[i].price);
        break;
    }
} Answer should be 30.00 but now getting 20.00

Comment: Its work equal to 70 and 70 + and less 130, So its check 70 to 129 qty means price 30.00.

Comment: You have some strange invisible character in the `meter` property name of `{"price":"20.00","‌​meter":"130"}`. That's why it doesn't work. If I fix the name it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/3zJYL/.

Comment: Thanks, I given var qty = 171.23; but alerting price is 20.00

Comment: Right, I fixed the code. Of course you also have to change `discounted_price` to `price`.